# robot_localization EKF node does not publish on /odometry/filtered (ROS2 Foxy)

Tags: ros, localization, ekf, odometry, ros2

I am using ROS2 Foxy and Gazebo 11 in Ubuntu 20.04. I have a URDF description of a mobile robot that uses 4 wheels for mecanum drive. Using the robot_localization package, I am creating an EKF node that subscribes to the `/wheel/odometry` topic, to which the mecanum drive node publishes the odometry data. Also, the EKF node is subscribed to data published by IMU. However, the EKF node is not publishing any data on `/odometry/filtered` topic. The node does publish some data on `/diagnostics` topic, but that does not seem to help me.
Here's my EKF config file-

```
ekf_filter_node:
    ros__parameters:

        frequency: 30.0
        sensor_timeout: 0.1
        two_d_mode: false
        publish_acceleration: false
        publish_tf: true
        reset_on_time_jump: true
        map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
        odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
        base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" if unspecified
        world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value of odom_frame if unspecified

        odom0: wheel/odometry
        odom0_config: [true,  true,  false,
                       false, false, true,
                       true, true, false,
                       false, false, true,
                       true, true, false]
        odom0_queue_size: 2
        odom0_nodelay: false
        odom0_differential: false
        odom0_relative: false

        imu0: imu
        imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                      true,  true,  true,
                      false, false, false,
                      true,  true,  true,
                      true, true, true]
        imu0_queue_size: 5
        imu0_nodelay: false
        imu0_differential: false
        imu0_relative: true
        imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
```

Here are the sample messages from the sensors:-

----IMU----

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 99
    nanosec: 1000000
  frame_id: base_link
orientation:
  x: -3.2484036403009136e-07
  y: -1.233682290372918e-07
  z: -5.640383185432385e-06
  w: 0.9999999999840328
orientation_covariance:
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
angular_velocity:
  x: -0.00017136447475541198
  y: 0.00013966822040950878
  z: 4.4918826200876715e-06
angular_velocity_covariance:
- 4.0e-08
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 4.0e-08
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 4.0e-08
linear_acceleration:
  x: -0.020305982380950664
  y: -0.005017642374176924
  z: 9.765243743038877
linear_acceleration_covariance:
- 0.00028900000000000003
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.00028900000000000003
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.0
- 0.00028900000000000003
```

----Gazebo Plugin that provides 4 wheel mecanum drive----

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 263
    nanosec: 153000000
  frame_id: odom
child_frame_id: base_link
pose:
  pose:
    position:
      x: 0.0005238049487633187
      y: -0.00013799493152156435
      z: 0.17620003865237005
    orientation:
      x: -1.5027791139302502e-07
      y: 8.421334553204312e-09
      z: -4.986068853738537e-05
      w: 0.9999999987569447
  covariance:
  - 1.0e-05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1.0e-05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1000000000000.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1000000000000.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1000000000000.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
twist:
  twist:
    linear:
      x: 9.15223527049435e-06
      y: 0.00028986655671066065
      z: 0.0
    angular:
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 3.0622019018612144e-05
  covariance:
  - 1.0e-05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1.0e-05
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1000000000000.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1000000000000.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 1000000000000.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.0
  - 0.001
```

Here's what the `/diagnostics` topic gets populated with:-

```
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1642601976
    nanosec: 319066940
  frame_id: ''
status:
- level: "\x02"
  name: 'ekf_filter_node: odometry/filtered topic status'
  message: No events recorded.
  hardware_id: none
  values:
  - key: Events in window
    value: '0'
  - key: Events since startup
    value: '0'
  - key: Duration of window (s)
    value: '9.999977'
  - key: Actual frequency (Hz)
    value: '0.000000'
  - key: Target frequency (Hz)
    value: '0.000000'
  - key: Maximum acceptable frequency (Hz)
    value: '0.000000'
```

Can you guys suggest what I might be missing here?

Comment: Would you mind removing the comments from the config file? Also, please include a sample message from every sensor input. Thanks!

Comment: @automatom I have included the sample messages from sensors and, as pointed out by you, removed `use_sim_time` from the config file. The issue still persists.

Comment: Oh, also, just checking: what does `ros2 topic info` say about the wheel odom and IMU topics? Is the EKF subscribed?

Comment: @automatom Yes, the EKF node is subscribed to the topics `/wheel/odometry` and `/imu`

Answer (score 1):

You need to include sample messages from your sensor inputs, but this sometimes indicates that the topic name, time stamp, or `frame_id` of the input message is incorrect.

EDIT: removing question about `use_sim_time` in ROS 2 in response to @Tully's point in the comments.

I was able to run your config from the command line in foxy:

```
ros2 run robot_localization ekf_node --ros-args --params-file ekf_params.yaml
```

I manually published messages to `imu` using the sample you provided, and the EKF was outputting messages on `/odometry/filtered`.

If I enable `use_sim_time`, it doesn't publish (it hangs [here](https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/blob/5d2e88268d988135af8642f4814cac7e2940cc87/src/ros_filter.cpp#L1991)), presumably because I don't have a time server running. If I manually publish to `/clock`, I get output again. Can you confirm that your Gazebo instance is publishing to `/clock`? If it is, then can you possibly provide a bag so I can see if anything else is wrong?

Comment: Re: `use_sime_time` In ROS 2 there's no global parameters so if you're working in simulation you need to set it on all nodes. If you're running in sim it should be set on all nodes.

Comment: @Tully neither inclusion nor exclusion of `use_sim_time` seems to work.

Comment: I was mostly addressing that to @automatom's question in the answer. It should be used in simluation as you had it. And I don't think is related to your problem.

Comment: @HarshitKaushik see this similar issue:

https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2_tutorials/issues/30#issuecomment-1022029601

Can you make sure you are getting data on `/clock`? If not, you'll need to make sure you are launching Gazebo correctly.