# What should be published in /clock when using a real robot?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to visualise my robot's odometry. I have a physical 4-wheel robot with me. They publish when the encoder ticks and the IMU values. To get the fused data and the `tf` from `base_link` to `odom` frame I am using the `robot_localization` package. Unfortunately, there is no data being published in `odometry/filtered` and `accel/filtered`.

This [issue](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/23115/robot-localization-ekf-node-does-not-publish-on-odometry-filtered-ros2-foxy) is similar to mine. The solution given there is to start Gazebo properly so that data gets published in the `clock/` topic. **But I do not want to simulate in Gazebo.** I have a physical robot with me!

Setting `use_sim_time` to *False* doesn't solve the problem.

This is my `eky.yaml` file used by the *robot_localization* node:

```
### ekf config file ###
ekf_filter_node:
    ros__parameters:
        frequency: 30.0
        two_d_mode: false
        publish_acceleration: true
        publish_tf: true
        #map_frame: map              # Defaults to "map" if unspecified
        odom_frame: odom            # Defaults to "odom" if unspecified
        base_link_frame: base_link  # Defaults to "base_link" ifunspecified
        world_frame: odom           # Defaults to the value ofodom_frame if unspecified

        odom0: encoder/odom
        odom0_config: [true,  true,  true,
                       false, false, false,
                       false, false, false,
                       false, false, true,
                       false, false, false]

        imu0: camera/imu
        imu0_config: [false, false, false,
                      true,  true,  true,
                      false, false, false,
                      false, false, false,
                      false, false, false]
```

Here is the `display.launch.py` file that I am using:

```
import os
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.actions import DeclareLaunchArgument
from launch.conditions import IfCondition, UnlessCondition
from launch.substitutions import Command, LaunchConfiguration
from launch_ros.actions import Node
from launch_ros.substitutions import FindPackageShare
from launch_ros.descriptions import ParameterValue
 
def generate_launch_description():
 
  # Set the path to this package.
  pkg_share = FindPackageShare(package='r23_description').find('r23_description')
 
  # Set the path to the RViz configuration settings
  default_rviz_config_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'rviz/rviz_basic_settings.rviz')
 
  # Set the path to the URDF file
  default_urdf_model_path = os.path.join(pkg_share, 'urdf/r23_description.urdf')
 
  # Launch configuration variables specific to simulation
  gui = LaunchConfiguration('gui')
  urdf_model = LaunchConfiguration('urdf_model')
  rviz_config_file = LaunchConfiguration('rviz_config_file')
  use_robot_state_pub = LaunchConfiguration('use_robot_state_pub')
  use_rviz = LaunchConfiguration('use_rviz')
  use_sim_time = LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')
 
  # Declare the launch arguments  
  declare_urdf_model_path_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='urdf_model', 
    default_value=default_urdf_model_path, 
    description='Absolute path to robot urdf file')
     
  declare_rviz_config_file_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='rviz_config_file',
    default_value=default_rviz_config_path,
    description='Full path to the RVIZ config file to use')
     
  declare_use_joint_state_publisher_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='gui',
    default_value='True',
    description='Flag to enable joint_state_publisher_gui')
   
  declare_use_robot_state_pub_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='use_robot_state_pub',
    default_value='True',
    description='Whether to start the robot state publisher')
 
  declare_use_rviz_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='use_rviz',
    default_value='True',
    description='Whether to start RVIZ')
     
  declare_use_sim_time_cmd = DeclareLaunchArgument(
    name='use_sim_time',
    default_value='False',
    description='Use simulation (Gazebo) clock if true')
    
  # Specify the actions
 
  # Publish the joint state values for the non-fixed joints in the URDF file.
  start_joint_state_publisher_cmd = Node(
    condition=UnlessCondition(gui),
    package='joint_state_publisher',
    executable='joint_state_publisher',
    name='joint_state_publisher')
 
  # A GUI to manipulate the joint state values
  start_joint_state_publisher_gui_node = Node(
    condition=IfCondition(gui),
    package='joint_state_publisher_gui',
    executable='joint_state_publisher_gui',
    name='joint_state_publisher_gui')
 
  # Subscribe to the joint states of the robot, and publish the 3D pose of each link.
  start_robot_state_publisher_cmd = Node(
    condition=IfCondition(use_robot_state_pub),
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    executable='robot_state_publisher',
    parameters=[{'use_sim_time': use_sim_time, 
    'robot_description': ParameterValue(Command(['cat ',default_urdf_model_path,]), value_type=str)}],
    arguments=[default_urdf_model_path])
 
  # Launch RViz
  start_rviz_cmd = Node(
    condition=IfCondition(use_rviz),
    package='rviz2',
    executable='rviz2',
    name='rviz2',
    output='screen',
    arguments=['-d', rviz_config_file])

  robot_localization_node = Node(
       package='robot_localization',
       executable='ekf_node',
       name='ekf_filter_node',
       output='screen',
       parameters=[os.path.join(pkg_share, 'config/ekf.yaml'), {'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration('use_sim_time')}]
  )

  DeclareLaunchArgument(name='use_sim_time', default_value='False', 
    description='Flag to enable use_sim_time'),

  # Create the launch description and populate
  ld = LaunchDescription()
 
  # Declare the launch options
  ld.add_action(declare_urdf_model_path_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_rviz_config_file_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_use_joint_state_publisher_cmd)
  ld.add_action(declare_use_robot_state_pub_cmd)  
  ld.add_action(declare_use_rviz_cmd) 
  ld.add_action(declare_use_sim_time_cmd)
 
  # Add any actions
  ld.add_action(start_joint_state_publisher_cmd)
  ld.add_action(start_joint_state_publisher_gui_node)
  ld.add_action(start_robot_state_publisher_cmd)
  ld.add_action(robot_localization_node)
  ld.add_action(start_rviz_cmd)
 
  return ld
```

Here is the sample data from [IMU](https://pastebin.com/n6V6SrUs) and [Encoders](https://pastebin.com/utsPi33y).

What changes do I need to make in order to get the `robot_localization` node to publish the `odom/filtered`, `accel/filtered` and the `odom` => `base_link` transformations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/411025/what-should-be-published-in-/clock-when-using-a-real-robot?/) by [tsadarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/70847/tsadarsh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2023-01-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am getting the values in the `accel/filtered` and `odometry/filtered` once I fixed my tf tree. I had to set the transforms between `odom` => `base_link`.

If you are using wheel encoders, [this](https://github.com/klintan/ros2_differential_drive) may help you transform wheel ticks to odometry data and publish the `base_link` to `odom` transformation.

If you are using an imu (I am using an integrated on: Intel Realsense D435i), [this](https://github.com/CCNYRoboticsLab/imu_tools) node publishes the required transformation. Check out [this](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/realsense-ros/issues/2563#issuecomment-1351852527) also.

---

Originally posted by [tsadarsh](https://answers.ros.org/users/70847/tsadarsh/) with karma: 78 on 2023-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-04-15**:\

> What should be published in /clock when using a real robot?

I'll point out that this is not an answer to the question in the title of this post.